# Azure file sharing and AD how to

Tags: azure, file-sharing, entra-id

I work for a small company, 5 users with Office365 standard license + email with custom domain.
We have an Azure account with a couple on VM for some legacy software.
We would like to set up a file share system like Windows server file share with permission on files and folder, we don't want to use OneDrive, moreover I 'd like to a have a proper AD to manage credentials, single sign on and so on. At the moment we don't have any AD.
I was thinking to set up a Azure Active Directory Domain Services and link it to a file share in a storage account and from there give permissions, but it seems it doesn't work like that.

From what I understand to achive what I want, please correct me if I'm wrong, I still need to have a Windows VM to mount the file share from the storage account and from there share it with all the permissione and users I want.
So I can remove Azure Active Directory Domain Services, create a small VM that act as Domain, sync it to Azure AD that is already install by deafult, I guess, since I'm using Office365, then mount the storage file share on the small VM and from there share it with all the permission, users and so on.
Or I can create Azure Active Directory Domain Services linked to Azure AD and create a small Windows VM join it to  Azure Active Directory Domain Services and than mount the storage file share, then share it with all the permission, users and so on.
Do I understand correctly or I'm completely wrong? or there is another option that I miss, or maybe a better way.

Comment: Another option would be to use Azure Files with an Azure storage account key for authentication to the shares. This doesn't give you the same level of granular permissions that a traditional file share does, but it eliminates the need for on premises AD or AD DS. You could create any number of shared folders in Azure Files and give access to the users and groups that need access. - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/#overview

Comment: The solutions you mentioned will greatly increase complexity, management and costs. It will not be worth it for 5 users. It's better to try to use modern tools to achieve your goals. Please specify why do you need this to be a file share. E.g. how it would be used, etc.